# Getting a column definition by name in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

For example:

```
<Grid Name="TestGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="TestColumnName" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I would like to be able to access the column definition in code using the name 'TestColumnName'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the x:Name property instead of Name :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
this.TestGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Where(c => c.Name == "TestColumnName").SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to develop your application.  This works for me just fine in Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: Working fine, just forgot about the x:Name.